# How do TensorFlow Lite's Float32 output-values represent an image?

Tags: java, android, tensorflow, bitmap, tensorflow-lite

## Issue

I can't get proper image values from the output of a TensorFlow Lite inference.

Using the `bitmapOut.copyPixelsFromBuffer` gets the wrong values.

For example - if I try to sample the first pixel from `bitmapIn` using `getPixel` (right after `bitmapIn = getMyInBitmap();` line), I get a value of `-4718617`. Sampling the first pixel from `bitmapOut` (after `bitmapOut.copyPixelsFromBuffer(outBuffer.rewind());`) I get a value of `1040252927`.

Also, not normalizing the image with `NormalizeOp`, gets all `0` values. So currently - I use the `NormalizeOp`, and after the inference I'm "denormalizing" the output one by one - but this takes a really really long time.

**How can I efficiently input a single image into a TensorFlow Lite Interpreter, and get a single image back**?

## Info

- I'm running a TensorFlow Lite inference on Android (Java).
- The TensorFlow Lite model takes an RGB 700x700 image `{1, 700, 700, 3}` as the input, and gives only the blue 700x700 image `{1, 700, 700, 1}` as the output.
- The model's Input and Output data types are both `FLOAT32`.

Here's my code for applying that inference on the image:

```
Bitmap bitmapIn, bitmapOut;
ByteBuffer inBuffer, outBuffer;

int[] inShape = tfliteInterpreter.getInputTensor(0).shape()
DataType inDataType = tfliteInterpreter.getInputTensor(0).dataType();
int[] outShape = tfliteInterpreter.getOutputTensor(0).shape()
DataType outDataType = tfliteInterpreter.getOutputTensor(0).dataType();

inTensorImage = new TensorImage(inDataType);
outTensorBuffer = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(outShape, outDataType);

imageProcessor = new ImageProcessor.Builder()
                        .add(new NormalizeOp(0.0f, 255.0f))
                        .build();

bitmapIn = getMyInBitmap();
inTensorImage.load(bitmapIn);
imageProcessor.process(inTensorImage);

inBuffer = inTensorImage.getBuffer();
outBuffer = outTensorBuffer.getBuffer();

tfliteInterpreter.run(inBuffer, outBuffer);

bitmapOut.copyPixelsFromBuffer(outBuffer.rewind());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still have no idea how to use `Bitmap`'s `copyPixelsFromBuffer` for translating the image bytes from a TensorFlow Lite's inference, but here's a solution for getting the image values correctly:

```
// create tensor buffers
TensorImage inputBuffer = new TensorImage([DATA_TYPE]);
TensorBuffer outputBuffer = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize([SHAPE], [DATA_TYPE]);
ByteBuffer output = outputBuffer.getBuffer();

// load input bitmap
inputBuffer.load(inputBitmap);

// run inference
tfliteInterpreter.run(inputBuffer.getBuffer(), output.rewind());

// translate inference bytes to bitmap pixels
int i, r, g, b;

float [] floatArray = output.getFloatArray();

for (i = 0; i < floatArray.length; i++) {

    // your RGB logic here:
    // using floatArray[i], r, g, and b

    outputBitmap.setPixel( i - (i / imageSize) * imageSize ,
        i / imageSize, Color.rgb(r, g, b));
}
```

If anyone has a more efficient way, or if anyone knows how to use `copyPixelsFromBuffer` kindly add your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that "de-normalizing" is a must-have, as it really looks like the model is generating float output in range [0,1] (could you help confirm that?) rather than byte value in [0-255] which the "copyPixelsFromBuffer" expects.

For the performance issue, do you have any numbers like how long do normalizing & denormalizing take?

Comment: I tried normalizing and de-normalizing, but that did not work. I still have no idea how to use bitmap's copyPixelsFromBuffer, but I've found another solution, and I'll post it here... thanks for the post :)